# Core Plot "numberForPlot" not Executing Properly

Tags: xcode, core-plot

I am trying to learn CorePlot.  I found a code example from "codejunkster" that I followed to the "T", but it is not working.  I narrowed it down to the numberForPlot method.  The code is below.  Neither of the conditions are true and I cannot figure out why.

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if ( [plot.identifier isEqual:@"chocoplot"] )
    {
        NSDictionary *bar = [self.dataForChart objectAtIndex:index];

        if(fieldEnum == CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation)
        {
            return [bar valueForKey:BAR_POSITION];
            NSLog(@"return [bar valueForKey:BAR_POSITION]");
        }
        else if(fieldEnum ==CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip){
            NSLog(@"return [bar valueForKey:BAR_HEIGHT];");
            return [bar valueForKey:BAR_HEIGHT];
        }
    }
   return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
}
```

Per the tutorial, below is a snippet of code which defines the CPTBarPlot...

```
// Create bar plot and add it to the graph
CPTBarPlot *plot = [[CPTBarPlot alloc] init] ;
plot.dataSource = self;
plot.delegate = self;
plot.barWidth = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"5.0"]
                 decimalValue];
plot.barOffset = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10.0"]
                  decimalValue];
plot.barCornerRadius = 5.0;
// Remove bar outlines
CPTMutableLineStyle *borderLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
borderLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor clearColor];
plot.lineStyle = borderLineStyle;

// Identifiers are handy if you want multiple plots in one graph
plot.identifier = @"chocoplot";

[self.graph addPlot:plot];
```

Comment: I did some more snooping.  the fieldEnum is equal to 1.  The CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation and CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip have value of 2 and 3 respectively.  How doe fieldEnum get it's value.  How does the CPTBarPlot method get/retain this value?

Comment: Is "chocoplot" a bar plot? What version of Core Plot are you using? The bar plot field enum changed after 0.9.

Comment: chocoplot is an identifier for the datasource and delegate methods for the graph/plot.  I am using the latest version of CorePlot that I downloaded using Mercurial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enum definition changed back in January:

```
typedef enum _CPTBarPlotField {
    CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation, ///< Bar location on independent coordinate axis.
    CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip,      ///< Bar tip value.
    CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase      ///< Bar base (used only if @link CPTBarPlot::barBasesVary barBasesVary @endlink is YES).
} CPTBarPlotField;
```

Make sure the `identifier` test is passing. If it is and the compiler still has the old enum values for some reason, try a clean build.

Comment: So, Eric, what you are shoewing above is the latest enum definitions per the latest version of CorePlot?  If I used these enums, what would happen to the comparison since they have no vluaes?

Comment: C enums always start counting from zero (0) if you don't specify explicit values. So location is 0, tip is 1, and base is 2.

Comment: I checked my header files and the CPTBarPlot.h contained values for the enums so it did not jibe with your version above.  I took another mercurial download and added it to the project and the enum condition for HEIGHT is true now and I get the bar graphs.  The one odd thing now is that although I compile clean with no errors, I alloc a CPTXYAxisSet variable but the variable and it's properties are not recognized.  Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug or you have initialized another type of plot.

Here's the declaration of `CPTBarPlotField`

```
/**     @brief Enumeration of bar plot data source field types
 **/
typedef enum _CPTBarPlotField {
    CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation = 2,  ///< Bar location on independent coordinate axis.
    CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip         = 3,  ///< Bar tip value.
    CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase     = 4      ///< Bar base (used only if barBasesVary is YES).
} CPTBarPlotField;
```

As you can see value 1 can't be returned by a CPTBarPlot. Check your code where you initialize the plot.

Comment: I have added the BarPlot allocation code to the original question bove.

Comment: Did you check that [plot.identifier isEqual:@"chocoplot"] returns true?

Comment: Yes.  If ytou notice, I placed the NSLogs within the actual conditions themsleves becasue the identifier test was passing each time.  I wanted to see which condition was being met after the identfier was validated.  Neither display is sent to the log.